# Steam not uninstalling properly on Ubuntu 32-bit

Tags: uninstall, steam

I installed `steam` but it wouldn't launch and found I should not have downloaded it from the Steam site, so decided to uninstall and try again. I uninstalled but find it still in the applications files if I search for `steam`.

I ran

```
sudo apt-get remove steam
```

and it says

```
package steam is not installed so not removed.
```

Same with

```
sudo apt-get purge steam
```

I also ran

```
re -rf `/.local/share/Steam && rm -rf ~/.steam
```

and it tells me

```
re is currently not installed. you can install it by typing sudo apt install re
```

So why is `steam` showing up in the applications if it is not there. How do I ensure I've completely gotten rid of it so I can do a clean install?

Comment: I assume that 're' is a typo for 'rm'?

Comment: yes sorry. autocorrect.